# Анимированный график на qwt жрёт оперативную память

Tags: c++, qt, память

Я написал программу, которая выводит график, перерисовывающийся с течением времени. Перерисовок происходит много. Но я не думал, что программа сможет потреблять **> 3 гигов** памяти...

Я пробовал всё: отключать `QwtPlotCanvas::BackingStore`, удалять по мере использования объекты, массивы, увеличивать время перерисовки - ничего не помогает. Теперь всё валю на метод `replot()`. А без него ничего не перерисуешь.

Что мне делать и как оптимизировать использование памяти?

UPD: Исходники:

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
this->setWindowTitle("Распределение температуры");
this->moveToCenter();
plot = new RealTimePlot();
QwtPlotCanvas *canvas = new QwtPlotCanvas();
canvas->setPaintAttribute(QwtPlotCanvas::BackingStore, false);
plot->setCanvas(canvas);
this->setCentralWidget(plot);
/*Это сейчас не имеет значения
back = new QAction("back", 0);
back->setText("<= Назад");
connect(back, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(clickBack()));
ui->mainToolBar->addAction(back);
next = new QAction("next", 0);
next->setText("Далее =>");
connect(next, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(clickNext()));
ui->mainToolBar->addAction(next);
*/
timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), plot, SLOT(timerHandle()));
timer->start(5);
}
```

realtimeplot.cpp

```
RealTimePlot::RealTimePlot()
{
counter = 0;
painter = new QwtPlotDirectPainter(this);
this->setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom, 0, L);
this->setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yLeft, 0, 30);
this->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::xBottom, "x");
this->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::yLeft, "T");
curve = new QwtPlotCurve("T(x)");
curve->setStyle(QwtPlotCurve::Lines);
curve->setPen(Qt::red, 2);
curve->setData(new CurveData());
//curve->setSymbol(new QwtSymbol(QwtSymbol::Ellipse, Qt::NoBrush, QPen(Qt::red), QSize(1, 1)));
curve->attach(this);
setAutoReplot(false);
setData();
}

void RealTimePlot::setData()
{
obj = new PhysObject(L);
x = new double[obj->n];
T = new double[obj->n];
for (int i=0; i<(obj->n); i++)
{
    x[i] = 0+i*(obj->dx);
    T[i] = (obj->getInTime(tcurr))[i];
}
curve->setSamples(x, T, obj->n);
}

void RealTimePlot::timerHandle()
{
if (tcurr < tmax){
    tcurr+=obj->dt;
    setData();
    replot();
}
//double dump = this->T[this->counter];
/*
QPointF newpoint = QPointF(this->x[this->counter], this->T[this->counter]);
this->counter++;
if (counter<=(obj->n)){
RealTimePlot::appendGraphPoint(newpoint);
}*/
}
```

Upd2. Как обычно, проблема решилась сама собой. Я взглянул на реализацию `PhysObject` и увидел, что метод `getInTime` при запросе каждый раз выполняет итерации `getNext()`, и с каждым разом их всё больше. Но зачем это надо?

Я перенёс все итерации `getNext()` в `reatimeplot.cpp`. Кол-во используемой памяти сократилось в ~200 (sic!) раз.

Comment: "перерисовывающийся с течением времени" Видать память не освобождается после очередного кадра.

Comment: И как же её освободить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `RealTimePlot::setData()` с каждой итерацией производится выделение памяти. Рискну предположить, что именно здесь и заключается проблема. С Qwt не работал, но, например, в QCustomPlot внесение данных графика производится похожим образом. Вероятнее всего выделять память под массивы требуется только один раз, а затем нужно лишь изменять значения по сохраняющимся в Qwt указателям. Если есть `QwtPlotCurve::setSamples()`, значит неподалёку притаился и `get...`.

Comment: Попробовал менять не все данные, а только сэмплы. На маленьких `L` и `tmax` получается хорошо, но, например, при `L=30` и `tmax=5` программа снова раздувается до 1,1 Гб.

Comment: @Byulent , а `new PhysObject(L)` всё также на каждой итерации выполняете? В этой строке, на мой взгляд, утечка, т.к. `obj` нигде не удаляется. Берётся из него некая `n`, которая обозначает скорее всего просто размер данных.

Comment: Да пробовал я уже `delete obj`, не помогало это как-то.

Comment: @Byulent , ну если на каждый `new` делали `delete`, то и проблем быть не должно. А вообще в справке к Qwt `QwtPlotCurve::setSamples()` объявлена в различных вариантах, в т.ч. и для вызова с векторами. Возможно имеет смысл попробовать эти варианты. А так, в коде у Вас проблема очевидна только в `setData()`. Метод `replot()` вряд ли является причиной утечки по многим причинам, он скорее следствие.

Comment: Я даже не соображу, куда вставить `delete`, чтобы программа не крашилась.